# Add AD Attributes to SQL Query Output

Tags: postgresql, powershell, active-directory

I use the following function to connect to a PostgreSQL database:

```
function Get-ODBC-Data{
   param([string]$query=$(throw 'query is mandatory.'))
   $conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
   $conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};Server=192.168.0.120;Port=7050;Database=datbase;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;"
   $conn.open()
   $comm = New-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query,$conn)
   $dase = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
   (New-Object system.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($comm)).fill($dase) | out-null
   $conn.close()
   $dase.Tables[0]
}
```

The below query returns all user ids and a user code. The user ids happen to match the Active Directory sAMAccountName attribute.

```
$query = "SELECT userid,code FROM pval_users"
$users = Get-ODBC-Data -query $query
```

Example content of $users:

```
userid   code
-------  ------
jdoe     34576
bmil     98765
```

I like to embed certain AD attributes to $users that are not stored in the database, making the output looking something like:

```
userid   First   Last   code
-------  ------  -----  -----
jdoe     John    Doe    34576
bmil     Bill    Miller 98765
```

What would be the 'best' solution to achieve this? I have an idea using `Get-ADuser -id $_.userid | select givenName, sn` but I didn't manage to get the output it in the order I need it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$Query = "SELECT userid,code FROM pval_users"
$Users = Get-ODBC-Data -query $Query

$Users | ForEach-Object {
    $ADUser = Get-ADuser -id $_.userid | select givenName, surname
    If ($ADUser) {
        $_ | Add-Member -Name 'First' -Value $ADUser.givenName -MemberType NoteProperty
        $_ | Add-Member -Name 'Last' -Value $ADUser.surname -MemberType NoteProperty
    }Else{
        Write-Warning "$($_.userid) not found in AD"
    }

    $_
}
```

Explanation:

- Uses `Get-ADUser` as you proposed to bring back the givenname and surname properties
- If a user is found in AD, uses `Add-Member` to add those properties to the current user item
- If a user is not found in AD, output a warning
- Outputs the user

Further, if you want to be a bit more dynamic and don't mind the property names in the final object being the same as they are in AD, you could do this:

```
$Users | ForEach-Object {
    $ADUser = Get-ADuser -id $_.userid | select givenName, surname
    If ($ADUser) {
        ForEach ($Prop in $ADUser.PSObject.Properties) {
            $_ | Add-Member -Name $Prop.Name -Value $Prop.Value -MemberType $Prop.MemberType
        }
    }Else{
        Write-Warning "$($_.userid) not found in AD"
    }

    $_
}
```

This uses a ForEach loop to iterate through all the properties returned by `Get-ADUser` and adds them to the current user in the `$Users` collection.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark! Exactly what I was looking for. I think option 1 will be suitable for my needs. At the moment I still have a small problem that the last name shows empty, although the field in AD is definitely filled.

Comment: I've amended the answer as such for future reference.

Comment: fyi: For me, the part that checks if an AD user exists `If ($ADUser)` did not work as expected. I replaced with `If ($?)` to check whether the last command was executed successfully.